# Unable to create SharePoint Search Application in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search

I had to remove a faulty Search Service Application. When removing the search app I ran into problems and ended up using **stsadm.exe -o deleteconfigurationobject -id "GUID"** among other commands to remove it from the Service Applications list. Ran psconfig at the end.

Trying to create a new Search Application, without any luck. Tried first from the GUI, and then with powershell.

Looks like there is a problem when creating the webservices in the application pool.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the PowerShell command below to remove the search service application.

```
$spapp = Get-SPServiceApplication -Name "<Search Service Application display name>"

Remove-SPServiceApplication $spapp -RemoveData
```

And then re-start the “SharePoint Timer Service” and “SharePoint Administration” service in services.msc.

Did you receive some error message when re-creating the new search service application? If you did, could you please share the error message?